# What is the technique can be applied into this logjam in Sudoku?

Tags: combinatorics, logic, game-theory, puzzle, sudoku

The difficulty of this Sudoku is Expert. I have tried to apply swordfish, X-chain but seems like it is not valid. But I am pretty sure is my problem because I am still new to the advanced techniques. And the values I putted into the cells are surely correct (because I opened auto-check for mistakes) and here is it :

[image]

I have stuck for more than 1 hour already.

Comment: I think this would be a better fit for puzzling.stackexchange.com.  It's not a math question.

Comment: Show that the entry in row 2 and column 5 cannot be 3.

Comment: @AnginaSeng thanks! But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak of any general technique, but I can look at Column 6.

In that column the fifth, sixth and eighth entries are all in the set $\{3,6,7\}$.  So those digits are knocked out of the remaining blocks of that column.  Thereby $7$ is fixed in Row 9 and $3$ is fixed in Row 1.

Have fun!

Comment: oh! That is Naked Triple! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Or, to honor a popular Christmas movie, the Triple Dog Dare!